# hibernate hql different between WITH and WHERE

Tags: hibernate, hql

Hi guys:
Im just studying about HQL

Could anyone explain or provide some links about different between WITH and WHERE in HQL?

fromhttp://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

example like:

> from Cat as cat
>       left join cat.kittens as kitten
>           with kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0

Can I replace **with** with **where** ?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`With` is used to "supply extra join conditions", which means that it is added to the join and not to the where clause:

```
from Cat as cat 
  left join cat.kittens as kitten 
  with kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0
```

will be translated to something like this;

```
from Cat as cat
  left outer join Cat as kitten
    on cat.id = kitten.mother_id 
      and kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0
```

while this

```
from Cat as cat 
  left join cat.kittens as kitten 
where kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0
```

is translated to

```
from Cat as cat
  left outer join Cat as kitten
    on cat.id = kitten.mother_id 
where
  kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0
```

Comment: Awesome, so detail! let me try it Thank you

Comment: In this example, Result is same? Am I right? Could you please provide some example with different result?

Comment: @user380690: No, it results *not* in the same, because of the left outer join. The first query returns all the cats in the database, and if they have kitten with a body weight of more then 10, it joins them, setting the columns for the kitten `null` if there aren't such (but still returning the cats). The second query only returns cats which *have* kitten with a body weight of more then 10.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing "with" with "where" restricts the result to Cats that **have** kittens with bodyWeight > 10.0. 
Using "with" gets even Cats with no kittens.